# How to setup Apache Atlas using embedded cassandra and Apache Solr

Tags: apache-atlas

**Step 1:** Clone the repository.
git clone https://github.com/apache/atlas

**Step 2:** Generated tar file by executing below command
mvn clean -DskipTests package -Pdist,embedded-cassandra-solr

**Step 3:** Once the build is successful, extracted ‘apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-server.tar’ file and executed below command.
.\bin\atlas_start.py

Seen below messages in console.

```
Starting Atlas server on host: localhost
Starting Atlas server on port: 21000
......................
Apache Atlas Server started!!!
```

But When I hit the url 'http://localhost:21000/', I am getting service unavailable message.

```
HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable
URI:    /
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    Service Unavailable
SERVLET:    -
```

Log files are empty, not sure how to identify the issue.

**Couple of Questions**

a. Do I need to explicitly setup cassandra and Apache solr for emebdded mode too? In that case please suggest me a documentation.

b. even though I generated the build using embedded cassandra file, while launching the application, it was still lokking for HADOOP_HOME property. Can I know the reason for this?

Comment: I can able to setup atlas by following this article https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2022/06/setup-apache-atlas-in-embedded-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and, after a while, I found that Zookeeper doesn't start at all; so, I stopped the Zookeeper service and restarted the installation of atlas. (Here is the link of the installation that I followed : https://manjitsingh664.medium.com/apache-atlas-installation-guide-9098df98d5c3.)

For your case, replace:

```
mvn clean -DskipTests package -Pdist,embedded-hbase-solr
```

with:

```
mvn clean -DskipTests package -Pdist,embedded-cassandra-solr
```